# Get only the top level categories using get_categories() without foreach loop

Tags: categories

Very simple Question: Here is my `get_categories()` code:

```
<?php $args = array(
    'show_option_all'   => '',
    'show_option_none'  => '',
    'orderby'           => 'ID',
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'show_count'        => 0,
    'hide_empty'        => 0,
    'exclude'           => '1',
    'hierarchical'      => 0,
    'depth'             => 1,
    'number'            => 12
    );
?>

<?php $categories = get_categories( $args ); ?>

<div class="middle-left">
    <ul>
        <?php for( $i=0; $i<4; $i++ ) {
            echo "<li>" . $categories[$i]->{'name'} . "</li>";
        } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="middle-middle">
    <ul>
        <?php for( $i=4; $i<8; $i++ ) {
            echo "<li>" . $categories[$i]->{'name'} . "</li>";
        } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="middle-right">
    <ul>
        <?php for( $i=8; $i<12; $i++ ) {
            echo "<li>" . $categories[$i]->{'name'} . "</li>";
        } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

After a long search I got the way how to get into the stdClass object without foreach loop and I want to proceed with this way. But I want only the top level categories, no subcats.

How can I modify the argument here?

Comment: downvoted because the Codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories should have given you the answer

Comment: @Michael Can't downvote your comment. :( If so, you failed to point that out, I'm afraid. :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`get_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) with a `parent` argument. From the Codex page for that function, emphasis mine:

> parent 
>       (integer) Get direct children of this term (only terms whose explicit parent is this value). **If 0 is passed, only top-level terms are returned.** Default is an empty string.

Untested, but this should do it.

```
$categories = get_terms( 
   'category', 
   array('parent' => 0)
);
```

Of course, you need to add any other arguments you require.

Answer (score 6):

set `parent` to `0`

```
$args = array(
  'parent' => 0,
  'hide_empty' => 0
);
```

Answer (score 0):

A native Wordpress solution to return the CURRENT parent category.

**You do not need to use foreach outside the function...**

```
function primary_categories($arr_excluded_cats) {

if($arr_excluded_cats == null) {
    $arr_excluded_cats = array();
}

$post_cats = get_the_category();

$args = array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'parent' => 0
);

    $primary_categories = get_categories($args);

    foreach ($primary_categories as $primary_category) {

        foreach ($post_cats as $post_cat) {
            if(($primary_category->slug == $post_cat->slug) && (!in_array($primary_category->slug, $arr_excluded_cats))) {
                return $primary_category->slug;
            }
        }
    }
}

//if you have more than two parent categories associated with the post, you can delete the ones you don't want here
$dont_return_these = array(
        'receitas','enciclopedico'
    );

//use the function like this:
echo primary_categories($dont_return_these);
```

Comments:

- if you only have one parent category by post, pass null instead of array
- if you want another output instead of slug change this to return $primary_category-> slug;